# Toilet is not flushing properly

Tags: plumbing, repair, toilet

When I flush my toilet it does not flush with power. It's very weak. I'm constantly plunging it, and there are times when the bowl doesn't fill completely.

Comment: Does the float appear to move throughout its range properly when flushing and refilling?

Comment: Low effort question. If you would like people to volunteer their time to help you, at least take the time to describe the problem in sufficient detail.

Comment: Is this a problem that just started or has it been an issue from first use?  If from first use is it a low water saving model?  I have a unit I installed new that is a low water type that fills about a quart sized bucket in the tank (not the tank itself), then dumps that on flush very low water use and poor function.

Comment: When did you last pour a cup of muriatic acid into the pipe leading to the top of bowl channels. If those channels are crudded up, you get a poor flush.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like two separate problems. Concerning the plunging problem I would bet there is a blockage in your wastewater pipe which needs to be unblocked by an Auger (Rotating Metal wire which dissolves the blockage). You can buy a short one from you Home Improvement Center and unmount the Toilet and use Auger to unblock the pipe. Sometimes the blockage is further away than the cheapy Auger can reach. Call a Plumber, they have a version for grown-ups.

The not filling bowl is usually related to the crappy quality of the parts inside the toilet water reservoir. You can shut off the water and take out the mechanics and replace it with a replacement kit. Pretty cheap. I do it usually every 5-10 year. Your Home Improvement Store has a whole collection of crappy Toilet replacement parts. Just bring your old once to find the correct replacement.

Good Luck